# jQuery Toggle Transform translate3 value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a javascript function which goes like this:

```
function toggle() {
  $('.sidebar').toggle();
}
```

And this I can some css for a sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
  transform: translate3d(-280px, 0px, 0px);
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  background: #263249;
  color: #eee;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

This sidebar is now hidden but when I run the toggle function I need it to toggle this value:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toggleClass

```js
function toggle() {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('newValue');
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    transform: translate3d(-280px, 0px, 0px);
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    background: #263249;
    color: #eee;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.newValue {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```